# Black screen instead of grub on every second boot

Tags: boot, 16.04, acer

I have Acer Aspire R11 R3-131T laptop. I installed Xubuntu 14.04 with full disk encryption, following [this guide](http://thesimplecomputer.info/full-disk-encryption-with-ubuntu). I then upgraded it to 16.04.

When I shut down my computer, on the first boot I get a black screen after BIOS screen, instead of Grub. The screen is completely empty, but the backlight of the monitor is on. I then have to restart the computer by holding down the power button. Sometimes this problem appears the second time. But usually the computer now shows Grub correctly.

- This is the only operating system on this computer
- HDD is the first boot option in the BIOS. Bios is in legacy mode (not UEFI) and it was also during installation.
- If I press enter during the black screen, boot does not continue
- This is unrelated to the issue with black screen after Grub, which I have fixed by adding `nomodeset` permanently to boot commands

The guide I used suggests that this could be issue with Plymouth or with initial ram disk. As suggested in [Plymouth documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/plymouth), I added required modesetting for Intel graphics card and configured Grub to use my native resolution. This did not help.

Starting Grub in console mode seems to work every time, so this is some kind of graphics problem.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: 'mkinitrd' I believe is only run when initrd doesn't exist but in your case it always does. 'update-initamfs -u' on the other hand only updates the file, never creates it.

Comment: are you dualbooting?

Comment: @MarkYisri This is the only operating system on this computer.